# Sencha Touch 2: Load a List from a store.queryBy result

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I had a List that used to work when it was bound directly to a store but now I want that list to get it's data from a queryBy on the original store.

Looking at the documentation is seems like setItems should do what I want.

```
var myStore = Ext.getStore('myStoreData');
var myData = myStore.queryBy(function(item) {
    return item.get('status') !== null;
});

// At this point myData looks valid and has the data I want.
// Ext.apply.create.Class {all: Array[5], items: Array[5], keys: Array[5], indices: Object, map: Object…}

Ext.getCmp('myListComponent').setItems(myData.items);
```

I keep getting the error "Object [object Object] has no method 'getItemId'".  I tried various other incantations but without success.   I also took a look at setData and add but without success.

========================

After getting Thiem's answer I just ended up creating a function that would create a filtered copy of an existing store and then just setting the List store to that.  Code below for others edification...

```
  storeCopy: function(store, filterBy) {
      var records = [];

      var allRecords = null;
      if(filterBy)
          allRecords= store.queryBy(filterBy);
      else
          allRecords= store.queryBy(function(){return true;});

      allRecords.each(function(r){
          var rec = r.copy();
          rec.setId(r.getId());
          records.push(rec);
      });
      var store2 = new Ext.data.Store({
          recordType: store.recordType
      });
      store2.add(records);
      return store2;
  },
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setItems` method does a totally different thing. For example, says you have an `Ext.Container` which consists of a form, some fields, and some interaction buttons. These things are call *child components*, or *items* of the container. They are oftenly declared in the `items` config of the parent container and `setItems` is designed to programmatically set the value of that config. So it has nothing to do with the store logic.

In your situation, here is one of the solutions:

- Create a store instance which contains filtered data.
- Use this command: `yourList.setStore('yourFilteredStore')`

And it should reload... hope this helps

Comment: Ouch, I missed that.  I will wait until I get to work on Monday so I can check a few things but I am pretty sure you are correct.

Comment: no problem, feel free to come back with other questions if you have